# Could not connect action to NSViewController

Tags: cocoa, xcode5, nsviewcontroller

I have a stupid problem with Xcode. Sometimes - and I don't know why, because I always follow the same procedure - if I create an IBAction from the nib file of my NSViewController to the .h-file of this NSViewController, I get the error "Could not connect the action buttonCancelClicked: to target of class NSViewController".

It's crazy, because the File's Owner is set to the .h-file and even if I click the button, the IBAction is called. Only Xcode throws this error.

Is this a bug of Xcode? Can I do something to remove this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSViewController serves to manage NSViews. Disconnect the button first. Declare the action in (maybe another) class, save, and read the header in IB again and connect it in IB the button. That's how I do it and never had a problem.

Comment: Thanks, that works (although I don't understand why)! I created a seperate NSObject and set it to the ViewController class

Comment: The cooperation between XCode and IB is not always reliable. I'm quite sure, the problem was not your fault.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that will generate this message is when the class identifier is not pointing to the correct Project. I had copied a class from one project to another.

My initial class identifier looked as follows:

[image]

This generated the console messages as shown in the original question.

I set the class then as follows:

[image]

This solved the problem.